# Get convert resultJsonFactory response to string in Magento2

Tags: magento2, json, array, conversion

I want to log the values of a resultJsonFactory object in php with in Magento 2:
How do I get the values I set in the $response object ?

```
$response = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
$response->setHttpResponseCode(404);
$response->setData(['message' => 'bla bla bla']);

//something like that but it dosn't work
$myMessage = $response->getData('message');
```

---

### **UPDATE**

I understand thant the getData is not set in the resultJsonFactory class but I can't find a way to get the values from the object.

What i am trying to get is the json string and the httpResponseCode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can retrieve it.
`$this->resultJsonFactory->create();` will return an instance of the class 
`Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json`.
the `setData()` method looks like this:

```
public function setData($data, $cycleCheck = false, $options = [])
{
    $this->json = \Zend_Json::encode($data, $cycleCheck, $options);
    return $this;
}
```

This means that the data you set is json encoded and there is no getData method on it.

Comment: Thanks Marius but must be a way to get the value in js i just jqXHR.responseJSON.message but have to be a way to do that in php